# using dygraph with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I recently started using dygraph and I quite enjoyed it so far.  I have tried to use it then with shiny without much success.  Although my script doesn't yield any errors, it also doesn't produce any graph!
Any chance you could guide me in the right direction?

here is a sample of my data:

```
> head(df2)
        date     Variety   Count Price Value Quantity TotalKg
1 2014-11-06 CRIPPS PINK   80-90   204  3670       18     333
2 2014-11-06 CRIPPS PINK 120-135   181 10150       56    1036
3 2014-11-06  CRIPPS RED   80-90   221 26910      122    2257
4 2014-11-06  CRIPPS RED 100-110   205 22910      112    2072
5 2014-11-06  CRIPPS RED 120-135   193 58950      306    5661
6 2014-11-06      TOPRED   80-90   167  7350       44     814
```

Using the Variety and Count variables, I would like to graph the price over time.

Here is my ui.R

```
library(dygraphs)
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Apples Prices"),

  sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("productname", "Select your product",
                        choices = levels(df2$Variety)),
            selectInput("count",  "Select your size",
                        choices = levels(df2$Count))),

            mainPanel(
              dygraphOutput("applesgraph"))
          )))
```

and the server side:

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dfa <- reactive({df2 %>% filter(Variety == input$productname & 
                                    Count == input$count )})

#the first graph which is price over time (input: variety, count, date)
  output$applesgraph <- renderDygraph({
   xts(dfa()$Price, order.by = dfa()$date) %>% dygraph()
  })
})
```

I can feel I am having the wrong approach with dplyr and time series object ... when should I filter then?  I have tried many combination, but then I have always errors such as "not subsetable".

Thanks in advance for any light / direction you can give me.

Comment: Everything is ok in your app. Your problem comes from your data input it seems. Can you somehow provide the data you are using or a more representative sample? (Here you only gave one date, so it is not handy to use it in the X axis)

Comment: Can you call `dput(df2)` and paste the contents to http://pastebin.com/ for instance. `str(df2)` doesn't help

Comment: here it is:  http://pastebin.com/iVsLKwAX

Comment: here is a link to the whole file if you need to:   https://drive.google.com/a/ifitwala.com/file/d/0Bwoj6Rk6h66NOUlxWWtwMnRxUUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say... Everything works neatly with your code. I can see the graps and the expected output changes when I test it with your data. Can you please try to update your dygraph, dplyr, shiny packages to see if this solves it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77560/discussion-between-faidherbard-and-franky).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you need the input data in `server.R` (for the graph) and in `ui.R` (for the input list), I added a `renderUI({...})` in `server.R` and an `uiOutput(...)` in `ui.R`

```
# server.R
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  data <- read.csv("cleanApples.csv") %>%
    filter(Quantity > 10)

  #the first graph which is price over time (input: variety, count, date)
  output$applesgraph <- renderDygraph({
    if (is.null(input$productname) || is.null(input$count)) return(NULL)
    filtered <- filter(data,
                       Variety == input$productname,
                       Count == input$count )
    xts(filtered$Price, as.Date(filtered$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
      dygraph()
  })

  output$productnames <- renderUI({
    selectInput("productname", "Select your product",
                choices = levels(data$Variety))
  })

  output$counts <- renderUI({
    selectInput("count",  "Select your size",
                choices = levels(data$Count))
  })
})
```

And

```
# ui.R
library(dygraphs)
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Apples Prices"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("productnames"),
      uiOutput("counts")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      dygraphOutput("applesgraph"))
  )))
```

Now it works [in shinyapps.io](https://faidherbard.shinyapps.io/joburgdygraph/)

Comment: thanks @faidherbard,   I can see it work nicely on your instance of shinyapps ;-)

Comment: unfortunately I stil do not know what I am doing wrong, but as you can see I go nothing.  http://frankyd.shinyapps.io/shinyApps4dygraph.   I really now just copied-paste your code.  and now I also got this warning:  `Warning in (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)`

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77560/discussion-between-faidherbard-and-franky

Comment: Thank you so much for all the time and enhancement you have provided.   I did learn a lot from you.  Unfortunately, it seems like the issue is with any shiny app and dygraph.  Even the one on their tutorial is not working for me (https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/shiny.html)  App is fine but no graph.  :-(   So I am still on the lookout on what is causing that conflict on my machine... Also, although we have the same code on shinyapps.io, your code display  the graphs and not mine.  Anyway ... thanks again for all your time and efforts!

Comment: Just in case it might be useful ...   ```> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dygraphs_0.4.4.1 shiny_0.11.1     manipulate_1.0.1